# Adding a reference to dll in VS

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, reference

I've got some strange behaviour in my project..
 I have one that needs to recieve o couple of forms from other project. Logic in theese forms requires some external dlls. So, I copypasted theese forms, added references, but i get an error "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies." So, after some time I decided to delete references in second project to see what i'm missing. And after adding theese references back i also got this error. How could this happen? 
 I thought that i missed some extra links in my first project so it didn't work, but is seems to be not exactly correct.

Comment: are those external DLLs being copied to the output directory?

Comment: Yes, they've been copied. Also i tried to add reference to existing path. Neither worked.

Comment: MSBuild will automatically copy dependent DLLs when it can see that the assembly uses them.  But if it can't, perhaps because you use Reflection or because they contain unmanaged code then it won't.  You then have to help and copy them yourself, typically by using xcopy /d in a post-build event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio for your development, you should be able to see all the added references under project references.

Make sure the dlls you are referring to show up under references. Then make sure you are importing the appropriate namespaces where you want to make calls to data or objects in your dlls.

You can view the name spaces by double clicking on the reference you want to view. It should give you list of all the methods and the namespaces they are under in object browser.

If everything is there, I would clean the solution and then rebuild the entire solution.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that the reference before deleting was ActiveX type and  after adding is assembly type. But how can i change a type of reference? The file on which reference points is exactly the same.

Comment: Try adding it as a COM reference. You do it the same way as you add a normal reference, but when the window comes up to select your file there should be a option to select COM and that should reveal your COM libraries. If you library does not show under COM then you'll have to register it.